# How to shorten laravel repeating routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

How to shorten this laravel route, I am trying to avoid to write code multiple times for one route.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'maindomain.com'], function()
  {
      Route::get('/signup', function () {
        return view('app.signup');
      });
      Route::post('signup', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepOne');
      Route::get('/signup2', function () {
          return view('app.signup2');
      });
      Route::post('signup2', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepSecond');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.maindomain.com'], function()
  {
      Route::get('/signup', function () {
        return view('app.signup');
      });
      Route::post('signup', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepOne');

      Route::get('/signup3', function () {
          return view('app.signup3');
      });
      Route::post('signup3', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepThird');
});
```

Where common code is

```
Route::get('/signup', function () {
  return view('app.signup');
});
Route::post('signup', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepOne');
```

I have made like below code but how to use in above route ?

```
$commonRoute = function(){
    Route::get('/signup', function () {
      return view('app.signup');
    });
    Route::post('signup', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepOne');  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place common routes outside a domain route group

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'maindomain.com'], function() {
  Route::get('/signup2', function () {
      return view('app.signup2');
  });

  Route::post('signup2', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepSecond');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.maindomain.com'], function() {
  Route::get('/signup3', function () {
      return view('app.signup3');
  });
  Route::post('signup3', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepThird');
});

Route::get('/signup', function () {
    return view('app.signup');
});

Route::post('signup', 'UsersController@saveSignupStepOne');
```

Or place common routes in another file named perhaps, common.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.maindomain.com'], function() {
  include(__DIR__.'/common.php');
});
```

Comment: Will both `maindomain.com/signup` and `subdomain.maindomain.com/signup` will work ? with above first code ?

Comment: Thanks @Ben , Its very good ans :), Dont' you think its good question too, And helpful to other.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Route::controller('signup', 'UsersController');
```

Comment: Beware that implicit controller  using `Route::controller` is deprecated on Laravel 5.2 https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `$commonRoute` as second parameter on `Route::group`

```
// Common route
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.maindomain.com'], $commonRoute);
Route::group(['domain' => 'maindomain.com'], $commonRoute);

// Others
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.maindomain.com'], function () {
    Route::get('test', function () {};
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'maindomain.com'], function () {
    Route::get('test2', function () {};
});
```

Comment: What about other one say `signup2` in first and `signup3` in second ?